# ie8 with imagemapster - position:absolute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using the imagemapster jQuery script (tooltip.js). My tool tips need to be `position:absolute`. This is running perfectly with the exception of:  Windows XP/7 IE8. This is the test page: http://cjehost.com/qt/panorama/testpages/examples/page2.html

Here is the html:

```html
<div class="blkBG pg1ToolTip1">
The last pair of chromosomes determines sex: Men usually have one X chromosome and one Y chromosome.
</div>
```

Here's the related css:

```css
.blkBG{border: none; background-image:url(http://cjehost.com/qt/panorama/testpages/examples/images/bg-black.png) !important;padding:10px; color:white; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;border-radius:3px; opacity: 0.9;position:absolute !important;line-height:1.15em;}
```

Comment: <div class="blkBG pg1ToolTip1">The last pair of chromosomes determines sex: Men usually have one X chromosome and one Y chromosome.</div>

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see this right away, but ie8 wasn't responsive. I added respond.js and it's running fine.